# Angular progress bar not moving with value change

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement a progress bar that moves in accordance with a process that's running in my Angular program.

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
        <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="loadingVal"></mat-progress-bar>

</div>
```

```
var loadingVal = 0 
var increase = 100 / array.length

for (i = 0, array.length, i++) {
    ....
    this.loadingVal = this.loadingVal + increase
}
```

As you can see, I am increasing the loadingVal with every iteration of the loop. However, the progress bar is not moving, it is staying at 0 until the process is complete. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to move the progress bar along?

[image]

Comment: This cannot work that way because JavaScript is single-threaded. Angular will run its change detection *after* the complete function returns. If you want to see some progress, try to use `window.setTimeout(() => this.loadingVal += increase, 500 * i);` within your loop. The `setTimeout()` function will queue those callbacks and Angular can perform the change detection inbetween. BTW: Try to write your for-loop this way: `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ... }`

Comment: I have the for loop written that way I just made a mistake while typing it quickly hahah. Could you show me what you mean with the window.setTimeout() in an answer please?

Comment: Just replace `this.loadingVal = this.loadingVal + increase` by `window.setTimeout(() => this.loadingVal += increase, 500 * i);`. Note: The second argument to `setTimeout()` is the time (in milliseconds) after which the callback should be called. I only used it here to slow down the progress bar animation.

Comment: I tried that, it seems to be no different. I tried declaring a const variable ```loader = 20``` and feeding that to the HTML and it still won't show. I think it is not passing value from TS to HTML..?

Comment: Did you also quote your expression in the template?

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways.

Comment: It seems my issue is that loading bar belongs to a different class than the variable. Do you know of a way to pass this variable between classes?

Comment: I created a little example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kciqoy

Comment: @majusebetter is it possible to declare the loadingVal in one component and then use it in a different one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237969/discussion-between-benmessi12040-and-majusebetter).

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work that way because JavaScript is single-threaded. Angular will run its change detection after the complete function returns. If you want to see some progress, try to use `window.setTimeout(() => this.loadingVal += increase, 500 * i);` within your loop. The `setTimeout()` function will queue those callbacks and Angular can perform the change detection in between.

**Example**

Controller:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  loadingVal: number = 0;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      window.setTimeout(() => (this.loadingVal += 1), i * 100);
    }
  }
}
```

Template:

```
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="loadingVal"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kciqoy

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. Is there a way to use the loadingVal variable in a separate component than the one it was defined in?

Comment: Yes, sure. You can for example pass `loadingVal` to some sub component, which defines an `@Input()` for it.

Comment: The reason I ask is because the loading bar is inside a mat-dialog, which is a separate component and class. I'll need to define the loadingVar in that component, but the for loop is in a different component. Can they pass information between the two?

Comment: Where exactly is @Input() used?

Comment: I updated the working example and added another component `ProgressBarComponent` which takes a `progress` value. Please have a look ;) Does it answer your question?

Comment: Progress value was defined within the same class that it was used no? I'm confused where progress is being incremented

Comment: Maybe if we go to chat I can show you what I mean more clearly?

Comment: I have the incrementing function defined in the home component. The home component is opening a mat-dialog which is defined in a separate function. Inside the dialog is the loading bar. I need to be able to increment the variable defined in the mat-dialog component from the home component. Does that make sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500964/passing-variable-in-between-components-in-angular I added some more detail to this question here if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be

```
[value]="loadingVal"
```

instead of

```
[value]=loadingVal
```

Comment: Neither works unfortunately